# missing template during ajax call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-for, missing-template

> I am getting the following error
>   *
>   Missing template quizzes/prev_question, application/prev_question with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,
>   :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views" *
>   "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"*

**In my view**

```
<%= form_tag(prev_question_path(:id =>@quiz.id), method: 'post', remote: true, :format => 'js') do %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
    <%= submit_tag("Prev",:class =>"btn btn-success") %>
```

**In my controller**

```
  def prev_question
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    @question = @quiz.questions.order! 'created_at DESC'.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {}
    end
```

**I have created a prev_question.js.erb file**

```
<% if !@question.option1.nil?%>
    $('#multiple-choices').show();
    $('#true-false').hide();
    $('#short-question').hide();
    $('#question_option1).val('<%= @question.option1%>')
    $('#question_option2).val('<%= @question.option2%>')
    $('#question_option3).val('<%= @question.option3%>')
    $('#question_option4).val('<%= @question.option4%>')
<%elsif !@question.anst.nil?%>
    $('#multiple-choices').hide();
    $('#true-false').show();
    $('#short-question').hide();
<%elsif !@question.anss.nil? %>
    $('#multiple-choices').hide();
    $('#true-false').hide();
    $('#short-question').show();
<%end%>
```

> Everytime I get the error that missing template, kindly let me know
>   what I am doing wrong I have looked over quite a few questions on
>   stackoverflow but no solution worked

Comment: What is the exact error you got? Please post it in the question.

Comment: try removing the `format js` from the view and add `respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
end`

Comment: remove the remaining formats.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

You need to respond to the js format when you make an ajax call.

```
def prev_question
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    @question = @quiz.questions.order! 'created_at DESC'.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {}
      format.js
    end
end
```

Comment: You can probably skip the `render file...` if your file is named `prev_question.js.erb`.

Comment: its not working I have tried adding format.js , same error

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaAltaf Can you post the log when you submit the form.? So that we can know the format expected by rails is js or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `prev_question` is only for AJAX, right?
Then why not just do this?

```
respond_to(:js)
```